# How to add TabBar in Navigation bar app

Tags: iphone

My first two view are Navigatinbased table view controllers. The third view is a tab bar with tabs based on selected row.

My problem is I am using TabBar based app so for first two view I have used presentModelView, but when user select a row I should open Tabbar view with same transaction(animation) as we have in navigation controller, Where on hiding the presentModelView have different transaction(animation).

Can any one help to know how I can show  tab bar view when user click on TableCell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:
http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/create-uitabbarcontroller/

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, I'm not sure what you mean but you can just create a UITabBarController in code and then push it onto the navigtion stack.

This will slide the tab bar view in from the right, just like with a normal view controller.

Comment: Is its a right approach.. I mean will apple approve my app since I am pushing tab bar in to navigation. And will it work, like I want "more" tab also in tab bar.

Comment: I don't know how the 'more' tab will behave since that would add a navigationController in a navigationController. You should try this and look at the results. I think Apple would approve it. I've seen other apps do this (although they didn't have a "more" tab).